# angularjs infinite scroll bottom top

Tags: angularjs, scroll, nginfinitescroll

I'm using [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll), but the default action is to load more items, when the bottom is reached, just like facebook timeline, but I need the opposite, I need to load the items, when the top is reached.

Is there a way to do that with ngInfiniteScroll or with another way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would be possible with nginfinitescroll, but i had to recently write my own. This code will load more data (10 at a time) into my scope.

**scrolled**

```
app.directive('scrolled', function () {

    return function (scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        var funCheckBounds = function (evt) {
            var rectObject = raw.getBoundingClientRect();
                //rectObject.bottom <= window.innerHeight for scroll to bottom
                if (rectObject.top >= window.innerHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attr.scrolled);
                }
           };
       angular.element(window).bind('scroll load', funCheckBounds);
    };
});
```

And of course put **scrolled** in your template.

Comment: I also just found this, maybe better for what you want to do:
http://nicolaspeters.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/angularjs-upwards-infinite-scroll/